# GREP exclude first 11 values

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, grep

I have a massive log file that I need to filter. In  this log, I want to display all logs that contain the string `dns` and I want see them just once.

i.e from this:

```
Dec  9 07:24:02 94.15.218.140 syslog: ssk:548.049:is_dns_hijack:1451:isDnsHijack=0
Dec  9 07:24:10 90.192.172.112 syslog: ssk:363.217:cmsLck_acquireLockWithTimeoutTraced:98:acquired lock. callerFuncName is_dns_hijack; timeout 12000 milliseconds
Dec  9 07:24:10 90.192.172.112 syslog: ssk:363.218:cmsLck_releaseLockTraced:144:lock hold time=0ms, acquiring lock callerFuncName is_dns_hijack; releasing lock callerFuncName is_dns_hijack;
Dec  9 07:24:10 90.192.172.112 syslog: ssk:363.225:is_dns_hijack:1425:isDnsHijack=0
Dec  9 07:24:17 94.15.218.140 syslog: ssk:563.048:cmsLck_acquireLockWithTimeoutTraced:95:acquired lock. callerFuncName is_dns_hijack; timeout 12000 milliseconds
Dec  9 07:24:17 94.15.218.140 syslog: ssk:563.048:cmsLck_releaseLockTraced:141:lock hold time=0ms, acquiring lock callerFuncName is_dns_hijack; releasing lock callerFuncName is_dns_hijack;
Dec  9 07:24:17 94.15.218.140 syslog: ssk:563.049:is_dns_hijack:1451:isDnsHijack=0
```

to this :

```
Dec  9 07:24:02 94.15.218.140 syslog: ssk:548.049:is_dns_hijack:1451:isDnsHijack=0
Dec  9 07:24:10 90.192.172.112 syslog: ssk:363.217:cmsLck_acquireLockWithTimeoutTraced:98:acquired lock. callerFuncName is_dns_hijack; timeout 12000 milliseconds
Dec  9 07:24:10 90.192.172.112 syslog: ssk:363.218:cmsLck_releaseLockTraced:144:lock hold time=0ms, acquiring lock callerFuncName is_dns_hijack; releasing lock callerFuncName is_dns_hijack;
```

Basically, it is the same log repeated more times due to a different timestamp.

I was trying to use `uniq` but in order to do that I need to remove the time stamp in the third column (achievable with  `awk '{ $3=""; print }'`) but as you can see from the log, the first 11 characters are different (i.e `ssk:563.048` - `ssk:563.049`). I was thinking of doing a `grep` with the word `dns` and trying to ignore the first 11 values.

How can I do this? Is there a better way?

Comment: To answer your specific question about ignoring the first 11 values (I believe you meant, in each line), check out the `-s, --skip-chars=N` option of GNU `uniq` ... man page describes this option like so: `avoid comparing the first N characters`

Comment: Thanks Murray. I'll have a look. What I want is ignore the first 11 characters of the column number six

Comment: If using GNU `uniq`, try combining the `-s` option with the `-f, --skip-fields=N` option (described as `avoid comparing the first N fields`, where `A field is a run of blanks (usually spaces and/or TABs), then non-blank characters.  Fields are skipped before chars.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `awk` and `:` as the field delimiter. Then, you can save each unique error message (which will be the 6th field) in an array and only print the first occurrence:

```
$ awk -F: '!a[$6]++' file 
Dec  9 07:24:02 94.15.218.140 syslog: ssk:548.049:is_dns_hijack:1451:isDnsHijack=0
Dec  9 07:24:10 90.192.172.112 syslog: ssk:363.218:cmsLck_releaseLockTraced:144:lock hold time=0ms, acquiring lock callerFuncName is_dns_hijack; releasing lock callerFuncName is_dns_hijack;
Dec  9 07:24:10 90.192.172.112 syslog: ssk:363.217:cmsLck_acquireLockWithTimeoutTraced:98:acquired lock. callerFuncName is_dns_hijack; timeout 12000 milliseconds
```

The script above will save each line as an entry in the associative array `a` only if there isn't already a value saved for the 6th field (`!a[$6]`). Because the default action in `awk` is to print when something evaluates to true, that will result in only the first unique occurrences being printed.

If you only want to do this for lines matching `dns`, use:

```
awk -F: '!a[$6]++ && /dns/' file
```

As for ignoring the 1st 11 lines, you could do that with:

```
grep dns file | tail -n +12
```

Comment: No need for the for loop in the `END{}` block, you can just `awk -F: '!a[$6]++' file` or if the 8th field is important too; `awk -F: '!a[$6,$8]++' file`

Comment: @chaos duh! You're right of course, thanks. I did it that way because I had misread and was originally keeping the last and not the first occurrence.

Comment: Hi guys, Thanks for your answers. My level is not really high and I'm struggling to understand the meaning of your scripts. I tried the second script and it seems that it works (don't know why but the output  puts 200 empty rows between each log)
Going back to something that is more readable for me, how can I write something more basic?

Comment: @Federiit doesn't really get much more simple than that. If you get empty lines, that means your input is not like what you show, you'll have lines that don't have a 6th field. The basic idea here is that awk will split each input line on `:` and the resulting fields will be `$1`, `$2` ... `$N`. The `a[$6]++` creates an array called `a` whose indices are the values of the 6th field. The `!` is a negation, so the `!a[$6]++` will be false the first time this particular 6th field is seen and, because the `++` adds 1, creating it, will be true the next time.